# Why Heating turns Amorphous to Crystalline and How?

Tags: physical-chemistry

I found this answer here but iam still confused:
"*Polymer chains are entangled and frozen in an amorphous state. The role of heating is to liberate these entangled chains, so some parts of chains are arranged in regular order, these regions are called crystalline regions. In between these ordered regions chains are randomly oriented.*"

**But these regularly ordered portions are already found in amorphous solids in scattered form in between of which the arrangement is disordered. That's why they are defined as having SHORT RANGE ORDER..**

Now what special happen when we heat them that they turn into Crystalline solid....

Comment: You allow them to diffuse around and find more highly ordered configurations that lower the free energy. Diffusion is (typically) an activated process, so you need to either lower the activation energy to move or increase the temperature.

Comment: You've misunderstood the term "short range order". In a melt or glass, you (e.g. an atom) can be quite sure that the center of your next neighbours are no nearer than the sum of your and their atomic radius, and not further away than perhaps 20% more. Beyond your next and perhaps second-next neighbour, everything is completely random.